# Get-hotfix on multiple computers and exporting to CSV

Tags: powershell, hotfix

How do I properly use $_ in out-file? Here's my code:

```
get-content computers.txt | 
  Where {$_ -AND (Test-Connection $_ -Quiet)} |
    foreach { Get-Hotfix -computername $_ } | 
      Select CSName,Description,HotFixID,InstalledBy,InstalledOn |
        convertto-csv | out-file "C:\$_.csv"
```

I'm trying to execute a get-hotfix for all the computers listed in the text file then I want them to be exported to CSV with the computer name as the filename.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking this isn't possible right? Based from my understanding $_ gets its value from the previous code block.

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to operate on each computer name stored in the file `computers.txt`.  True?  If so, then you need to use `foreach` on the result of `get-content`, since that gives you an array of strings containing each line of the file.  I think it might be easier to figure out if you used some variables to get intermediate results, then operated on those results in subsequent lines.  Is it necessary to use a single line command?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I need to execute get-hotfix on every computer listed in the text file.

Wouldn't this work?
`foreach {Get-Hotfix -computername $_}`

And no, a single-line command isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one pipeline to process the computers.txt files, and a nested one inside the `foreach` to process the list of hotfixes for each computer:

```
get-content .\computers.txt |
  Where {$_ -AND (Test-Connection $_ -Quiet)} |
    foreach { 
      Get-Hotfix -computername $_ |
        Select CSName,Description,HotFixID,InstalledBy,InstalledOn |
          convertto-csv | out-file "C:\$_.csv" 
    }
```

**Edit:** Changed `computers.txt` to `.\computers.txt`, as this is required for local paths in powershell

Comment: Why does it says `Get-Content : Cannot find path C:\script\computers.txt' because it does not exist.`

I'm executing it on the folder wherein computers.txt is stored

Comment: Paths always need to be qualified in powershell, it's a security "feature."  So you need to change your argument from `computers.txt` to `.\computers.txt`.  I will udpate my answer with the same.

Comment: Note also that `ConvertTo-CSV | Out-File` can be simplified to just `Export-CSV` if you like

Comment: Still won't work. I tried adding -path but same error occurs.

Comment: Well it sounds like you have other, unrelated, issues.  Does `dir .\computers.txt` return anything?  If so, you can pipe `dir .\computers.txt | Get-Content | ...`.  If not, the file isn't there - maybe you have the filename wrong or you are in the wrong provider.

Comment: Note that paths as command _arguments_ need _not_ be qualified - that requirement only applies to _invoking executables_ located in the current directory; in other words: `Get-Content computers.txt` works just fine, assuming `computers.txt` is located in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

i can see with this:
get-content .\computers.txt | Where {$_ -AND (Test-Connection $_ -Quiet)} | foreach{ Get-Hotfix -id KB4012212 -computername $_ | Select CSName,Description,HotFixID,InstalledBy,InstalledOn | convertto-csv | out-file "C:\$_.csv" }
i can see only in which PC is the fix (KB4012212)  installed.
it's possible to see the following

- CSNAME   Fix(Inst/NotInst)

  PC1      FIxInstalled

  PC2      FixNotinstalled

  PC3      FixnotInstalled

..
..
etc

Answer (score 0):

I monkeyed with this for a while and nothing I found on-line worked until I used this combo.

I used the method is this thread but it was SO slow and I wanted to learn more about using jobs so this is what ended up working for me on Windows 7 PS Ver 4.
All other options were either too slow or did not return data from the remote system.

```
$VMs = get-content C:\WinVms.txt #Generate your hostnames list however you deem best.
foreach ($vm in $vms)
{
Write-Host "Attempting to get hotfixes on:" $vm
invoke-command -computername $vm -ScriptBlock {start-job -scriptblock {(get-hotfix | sort installedon)[-1]} | wait-job | receive-job} -AsJob
}
start-sleep 60 # give it a minute to complete
get-job | ? { $_.state -eq "Completed"} | receive-job -keep | export-csv c:\temp\win-patch.csv
```

you can check your failures too like this:

```
get-job | ? { $_.state -eq "Failed"}
```