# output results from a Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, hotfix

Although I have searched, I a cannot find (or have the PS knowledge) on how to create a Powershell script for discovering what 'Hot fixes' are installed on devices contained in a text file (`c:\devices.txt`) & output  the results in another file (e.g. `c:\HFStatus.txt`).

I would be so grateful if someone could assist and compile this for me?

MTIA
TM3007

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Getting a list of hotfixes? Iterating a list of computers? Saving the results?

Comment: The [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083341/get-hotfix-on-multiple-computers-and-exporting-to-csv) has additional requirements, but I hope it has all the information you need; in short: use [`Get-HotFix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix)